# Using abstract requests with Feign

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jackson, feign

I'm trying to use an interface as the RequestBody in Feign, but Feign is creating an empty object as the request. Is this not possible or am I doing something wrong here? I could not find anything on that topic so far.

This is a simplified example of what I am trying to do (in reality there are 3 different kinds of requests)

```
interface BookingClient {
    @RequestLine("POST /booking")
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    fun createBooking(request: BookingRequest): BookingResponse
}

interface BookingRequest
data class NormalBooking(
    val product: String
): BookingRequest
data class DiscountedBooking(
    val product: String,
    val discountCode: String
): BookingRequest

// Client Configuration
val client = Feign.builder()
        .client(feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient())
        .errorDecoder(BadEntityErrorDecoder())
        .encoder(JacksonEncoder())
        .decoder(JacksonDecoder(listOf(KotlinModule(), JavaTimeModule())))
        .logger(feign.Logger.JavaLogger())
        .logLevel(feign.Logger.Level.FULL)
        .target(BookingClient::class.java, mockServer.getUrl())
```

If I now call `createBooking()` with either implementation, Feign always serializes

```
{}
```

instead of

```
{
    "product": "productA"
}
```

and

```
{
    "product": "productA",
    "discountCode": "discountCode"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is parameter type, when we invoke Feign.target(...), Feign start to parse your BookingClient to a Http request template, and body type is BookingRequest, so Feign always serializes "{}"

```
interface BookingClient {
    @RequestLine("POST /booking")
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    // BookingRequest should change to NormalBooking or DiscountedBooking
    fun createBooking(request: BookingRequest): BookingResponse
}
```